# retrieve data from yahoo api using csv files

Tags: csv, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

i'm trying to retrieve currencieshistorical data by csv files from yahoo finance
using this:
"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=NZDGBP=X&a=01&b=01&c=2004&d=31&e=10&f=2016"
but itsnot working..
someone know what is wrong or what is the right way to retrieve currencies data from yahoo?

Comment: You must provide a link to some documentation where you found that your URL should work.

Comment: Are you looking in [Yahoo Developer Network](https://developer.yahoo.com)?  Should be plenty of documentation.

Comment: I saw this url after simple searching in google... i dont have big knowledge in all that networks and etc.